# How to do simple SSH x11 forwarding

Tags: go, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to implement ssh x11 forwarding in Go, referring to Paramiko's source, but it does not work well.

The x11-req request seems to be successful, but fails with OpenChannel.
Isn't there any better way?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-6.3.2

The full code is here.

https://gist.github.com/blacknon/6e2e6e2c0ebcd64c381925f0e3e86e42

```golang
package main

(omit)

func main() {
    // Create sshClientConfig
    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: user,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(pass),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    // SSH connect.
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port, sshConfig)

    // Create Session
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    defer session.Close()

    // NOTE:
    // x11-req Payload
    payload := x11request{
        SingleConnection: false,
        AuthProtocol:     string("MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1"),
        AuthCookie:       string("d92c30482cc3d2de61888961deb74c08"),
        ScreenNumber:     uint32(0),
    }

    // NOTE:
    // send x11-req Request
    ok, err := session.SendRequest("x11-req", true, ssh.Marshal(payload))
    if err == nil && !ok {
        fmt.Println(errors.New("ssh: x11-req failed"))
    }
    fmt.Printf("x11-req: %v\n", ok)
    fmt.Println("-----")

    // x11 OpenChannel (Not working...)
    x11Data := x11channel{
        Host: "localhost",
        Port: uint32(6000),
    }

    sshChan, req, x11err := client.OpenChannel("x11", ssh.Marshal(x11Data))
    fmt.Println(sshChan) // DEBUG
    fmt.Println(req)     // DEBUG
    fmt.Println(x11err)  // DEBUG

    (omit)
}
```

I added sshd side debug log.

```
sshd[1811]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request x11-req reply 1
sshd[1811]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
sshd[1811]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req x11-req
sshd[1811]: debug1: channel 1: new [X11 inet listener]
sshd[1811]: debug1: channel 2: new [X11 inet listener]
sshd[1811]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 1 win 2097152 max 32768
sshd[1811]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: failure x11
```

Thanks guys! Thanks to it, I was able to implement it safely. Have a working code.

https://gist.github.com/blacknon/9eca2e2b5462f71474e1101179847d2a

Comment: "...but fails with OpenChannel." This isn't very informative. What exactly happens then? Is the server logging any useful error messages?

Comment: sorry. I added sshd side debug log.

Answer (score 1):

```
// x11 OpenChannel (Not working...)
x11Data := x11channel{
    Host: "localhost",
    Port: uint32(6000),
}

sshChan, req, x11err := client.OpenChannel("x11", ssh.Marshal(x11Data))
```

The fundamental issue here is that X11 forwarding channels are initiated from the SSH server to the SSH client. You're trying to open an X11 channel from the client to the server. This isn't supported by your server, and it isn't the usual way to use X forwarding.

I'm not a go programmer. But after looking [the documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh), after your send your x11-req it looks like you would call [client.HandleChannelOpen()](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Client.HandleChannelOpen) to receive X11 channel requests coming from the server.

More background: To be clear, start with the terminology. Your program is an *ssh client* and it connects to an *ssh server*. With X, the *server* is the program which controls a display, keyboard, and mouse. *X clients* are programs like xterm and xeyes which connect to a server to display windows and do similar things.

When you want to forward X11 through SSH, the ssh client will send an X11 request to the ssh server. This tells the server that the client wants X11 forwarding for the connection. The server will perform some setup and open a TCP listening port to receive connections from X clients.

When an X client connects to the ssh server's X11 listening port, the ssh server will open a channel back to the ssh client. The ssh client will connect to the local X server, and the ssh client and ssh server will relay data between the X server (local to the ssh client host) and the X client (local to the ssh server host). Each channel handles a single X client.

So a program such as yours has to send a request to the server, signalling that your program wants to forward X11 through the ssh connection. The actual x11 channels will be opened on demand from the ssh server to the ssh client when an X client tries to use the forwarded X11 service.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that I misunderstood it! It was possible to implement based on what you taught!